I have to fetch book id for top 3 average rated books here from firestore database
Attached is the reference from the firebase
I am saving data as here
enter image description here
    const productRef = await addDoc(collection(db, `rating_book/${product.bk_ID}/ratings`), {
      bookId: product.bk_ID,
      date: Timestamp.now(),
      rating: rating,
      token: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!).token,
      username: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')!).username
    });

This is another snapshot for complete picture from firebase.
enter image description here
I am trying to fetch data but i am not getting data here. why?
  const fetchTopRatedBookIds = async() => {
    try {
      const ratingsSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'rating_book'));
      const bookRatings: { [bookId: string]: number[] } = {};
  
      await Promise.all(ratingsSnapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
        const ratings = doc.data().ratings as number[];
        bookRatings[doc.id] = ratings;
        console.log(`Book ID: ${doc.id}, Ratings: ${ratings}`);
      }));
  
      const averageRatings = Object.entries(bookRatings).map(([bookId, ratings]) => ({
        bookId,
        averageRating: ratings.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr, 0) / ratings.length,
      }));
  
      console.log('Average Ratings:', averageRatings);
  
      const sortedBooks = averageRatings.sort((a, b) => b.averageRating - a.averageRating).slice(0, 3).map(entry => entry.bookId);
      console.log('Sorted Books:', sortedBooks);
  
      return sortedBooks;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching details', error);
      return [];
    }
  };

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Your code is adding documents to individual subcollections called (ratings) nested under documents within ratings_book:
addDoc(collection(db, `rating_book/${product.bk_ID}/ratings`)

These ratings subcollections are completely different than rating_book.
Your query is only considering documents immediately within rating_book instead of the nested collections:
await getDocs(collection(db, 'rating_book'))

This query is always going to return no documents, because there are no documents immediately within in the rating_book collections.
Firestore queries are shallow and do not consider nested subcollections.
If you want to query all of the documents in the ratings subcollections, you need to use a collection group query instead using the name of the subcollection where the documents actually live:
await getDocs(query(collectionGroup(db, 'ratings')))

Either that, or do not add the documents to nested subcollections at all and instead use a single collection for all of the documents.
